# Get child level in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

- while doinf a MLM Project, I am able to get the hierarchy of the users and its child using below query

  ```
  SELECT t1.id AS lev0, t2.id AS lev1, t3.id AS lev2, 
                   t4.id AS lev3,t5.id AS lev4,t6.id AS lev5,
                   t7.id AS lev6  
  FROM users AS t1
          LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t2.referred_by = t1.id
          LEFT JOIN users AS t3 ON t3.referred_by = t2.id
          LEFT JOIN users AS t4 ON t4.referred_by = t3.id
          LEFT JOIN users AS t5 ON t5.referred_by = t4.id
          LEFT JOIN users AS t6 ON t6.referred_by = t5.id
          LEFT JOIN users AS t7 ON t7.referred_by = t6.id 
  WHERE t7.id='$uid'";
  ```
- i want to know the level of a particular user searched from the
  database on the basis of his id so that some amount get distributed to his parent and grandparents
- for ex: 1->2->3->4->5, here '5' is at level 5..I want to know how to get this in mysql whenever i enter user id '5'..how to do this...thanks for any help ..
- every member can have unlimited child members

here is the table structure

---

`| id| username| email  | referred_by |
      |  1|  abc    |mail.com|             |
      |  2|  xyz    |mail.com|    1        |
      |  3|         |mail.com|    2        |
      |  4|         |mail.com|    3        |
      |  5|         |mail.com|    4        |`

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: your example doesn't match with your table structure.

Comment: Perhaps left_id and right_id? [Quick Explanation](http://www.evanpetersen.com/item/nested-sets.html) I found via google.

Comment: @Jhecht thanx..but i can't check left right since at each level user can have multiple referrals not just 2 childs... :(

Comment: To clarify something: are you saying that each node can have MULTIPLE parents?

Comment: sorry fr mistyping...i meant multiple childs.

Answer (score 0):

You better add field `hierarchy_level` to your table and set it each time you add a new user (`hierarchy_level = referred_user.hierarchy_level + 1`).

If you don't edit user's referrers often, that will be perfect solution. Otherwise you should update you records each time you change the hierarchy.

If you need to get the hierarchy of the users often, you should also add a field, that describes a hierarchy for each user. Example:

```
  | id| username| email  | referred_by | hierarchy
  |  1|  abc    |mail.com|             |
  |  2|  xyz    |mail.com|    1        | 1
  |  3|         |mail.com|    2        | 1,2
  |  4|         |mail.com|    3        | 1,2,3
  |  5|         |mail.com|    4        | 1,2,3,4
```

The query you provided costs a lot and it doesn't reveal the full hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @Heavy..I just want to distribute amount to 6 levels of a particular user..thats why i have used Adjacency list model..